Desktop app to edit (cut/paste) an AC-3 audio file without re-encoding
I would like to discover a program for Windows, with a graphical user interface, that is capable to load an AC-3 audio file to cut (and paste) at some points of the audio stream, without re-encoding the audio.
When I think about this type of application, ideally in my mind it would have similarity to the user interface of mp3DirectCut:

Requisites:

Freeware (open-source or not, it does not matter), or Freemium (partially free with disabled premium features).
Works in Windows 10 (x64).
With graphical user interface (GUI) where you can select a range, so you don't need to manually enter the timecodes to cut.
Has an audio stream visualizer (or "wave visualizer"), like in the screenshot above.
Can play the audio, cut at any point, and paste a silence at any point.
Lossless editing (i.e.; it does not require to re-encode the audio file).
Supports stereo or 5.1 channels.

Note: paid software suggestions are welcome too, if they are economic for private use (not coorporative solutions that costs hundreds or thousands of money).
UPDATE:
DelayCut is the closest software I could find, but at the same time it is very far from what I need.
This program works in a lossless way for AC-3 files, but the user interface is presented in a way that, without a wave visualizer that allows you to play the audio, and to select a segment of the audio to cut (or where to insert a silence or paste) it becomes practically useless for many audio editing tasks.
It is a really tedious program, where you cannot even enter time codes (like "00:01:10") for ease of use, but rather requires entering absolute values in milliseconds (or in other allowed and annoying formats, like total seconds, or frames).

I found the following project that may help you.  I haven't tried it myself, so I'll simply mention it here as a comment instead of an answer.  https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut
